# How to run two React projects on one domain?

Tags: reactjs, nginx, routes

I am new to the server configuration. I have two running React projects on [Linode](https://www.linode.com/) server as `port` `3000` and `5000`. The two React projects are different. The port `3000` is for homepage and port `5000` for admin page. Now I also purchased domain name as https://www.testeam.com. How can I map domain name to my react projects as following?

```
+-------|---------------|-----------------------------+
| Page  | react project | Domain Name                 |
+-------|---------------|-----------------------------+
| Home  | port 3000     | https://www.testeam.com     |
+-------|---------------|-----------------------------+
| Admin | port 5000     | https://www.testeam.com/app |
+-------|---------------|-----------------------------+
```

Note : The admin page is accessed using different directory `app`.

Comment: Ideally you would use a `subdomain.domain.com`. Then you create a `CNAME` record to `*.subdomain.domain.com` and an  `A` record to `subdomain.domain.com`. Then in your `nginx` config you would route all requests to the subdomain to the other app folder. Then you could access the admin app like so: `admin.testteam.com`

Comment: @MattCarlotta, Instead of subdomain, shall I do different directory?

Answer (score 1):

You can use reverse proxies for nginx. Please read more about this topic [here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/)

Assuming you only want to serve these in https, this would be the suggested server block for port 443:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name testeam.com www.testeam.com;

    # to map "Home" page
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        # add other proxy configurations here
    }

    # to map "Admin" page
    location /app/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        # add other proxy configurations here
    }

    # include SSL configurations here
}
```

Add:
If you want to make sure this works prior to adding in SSL configurations, you can use the same server block but change `443` to `80`. When you're happy with it, use port 80 only to redirect to https, then use the server block above to serve pages in https,

Hope this helps!